# Warning: `Array{T, 1}(m::Int) where T` is deprecated, use `Array{T, 1}(undef, m)` instead. Julia

Tags: julia

I am doing the conversion from Julia v0.6 to v0.7.  I get the following error in my code at runtime:

**Warning: `Array{T, 1}(m::Int) where T` is deprecated, use `Array{T, 1}(undef, m)` instead.**

I went and looked at what it was referencing and it was not clear what I was supposed to change.  Can anyone elaborate on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

currently you are declaring the array as:

```
someArray = Array{SomeTypeHere}(someIntegerHere)
```

however this way of allocating an array is now deprecated and will not work on Julia 1.0, instead if you wish to allocate an array of uninitialized values you should write it as:

```
someArray = Array{SomeTypeHere}(undef,someIntegerHere)
```